# PySpark Dataframe extract column as an array

Tags: python, pyspark

Is it possible to extract all of the rows of a specific column to a container of type array?

I want to be able to extract it and then reshape it as an array. Currently, the column type that I am trying to extract is of type udt.

I tried to use

```
my_array =  df.select(df['my_col'])
```

but this is not correct as it gives me a list

Comment: To clarify, you are not looking for a Python `list`, but something like [`pyspark.sql.types.ArrayType`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.types.ArrayType.html)?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Yes you are correct. I need to be able to reshape() it so that I can pass it into function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

collect_list() gives you an array of values.

A. If you want to collect all the values of a column say c2, based on another column say c1, you can group by c1 and collect values of c2 using collect_list.

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([
    ('emma', 'math'),
    ('emma', 'english'),
    ('mia','english'),
    ('mia','science'),
   ('mona','math'),
   ('mona','geography')
], ["student", "subject"])

from pyspark.sql.functions import collect_list
df1=df.groupBy('student').agg(collect_list('subject'))
df1.show()
```

B. If you want all values of c2 irrespective of any other column, you can group by a literal:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit

df1=df.groupBy(lit(1)).agg(collect_list('subject'))
df1.show()
```